# What is the use of InsertVisible property of BoundField in a GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Can any one explain to me what the use of "InsertVisible" property of `BoundField` in a `GridView` is and at what conditions we should use it? I have seen the description on msdn.com but I am not able to understand exactly.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

The `GridView` control is not designed for inserting data.  Thus, this explanation is more applicable to a `DetailsView` or a `FormView`.

When you put a databound control into "insert mode", it turns all of the `BoundField`s into user input controls (`TextBox`s, `CheckBox`s, etc) by default.  `InsertVisible` allows you to change this as follows:

- **InsertVisible = true**: A user-input control will be generated.  This allows a user to enter a value for that field into your datasource.
- **InsertVisible = false**:  A user input control *is not to be generated*, thus the user is not given the opportunity to enter a value.

  - This is especially useful if you plan to programatically fill out that field (with an auto-generated ID or some calculated value).

Here is the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfield.insertvisible.aspx) as a reference (I realize you mention that you read the article, this is just for the sake of completeness).

Comment: hi @jadarnel27: i tried using InsertVisible="false" for one of my databoundfield in gridview and still that field was visible while editing, how can i make the field non-editable in edit-mode in databound controls

Comment: @Abbas You need to use the `ReadOnly="true"` property to make the field non-editable.

Comment: if i make the ReadOnly="True" i am unable to read the values from the field, actually there is a field known as username, which i dont want user to update, but the update query for the row is based on username only, so i need to read the value for the username, so i am unable to read the username field if it is read only